# No ':' in the url

Tags: minecraft, url

Starting fairly recently whenever I open the Minecraft launcher I get this error message

```
Invalid url: '/home/kailas/Downloads/Minecraft.jar' given, exiting
No ':' in the uri
```

What does this mean? I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your program expects something in the form of :

`file:///home/kailas/Downloads/Minecraft.jar`

For more information on url syntax, read this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) article.