# No ':' in the uri

Tags: 18.04

Im trying to download firestorm but when I try to run the install.sh it says

```
Invalid url: '/home/user/Downloads/Pheonix_FirestormOS-Releasex64_x86_64_5.1.7.55786/install.sh' given, exiting
No ':' in the uri
```

Can  someone explain what this means? I already looked at this: [No ':' in the url](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617041/no-in-the-url) but it wasn't helpful. How do I fix this? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.01

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the question you linked, and I would imagine the solution is the same (i.e. use `file:///home/user/Downloads/...` instead). How was it not helpful?

Comment: I don't know what it means by that, I don't know  how to get file:///

Comment: OK, how are you running the install.sh?

Comment: Im running it using AptURL

Comment: OK, I'm confused, cause AptURL doesn't run shell scripts. Please describe exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I right click it and it wants to run it through AptURL

Comment: Right-click what? And what is telling you that it wants to run through AptURL? Maybe it would be best if you posted a screenshot.

Comment: I right click the install.sh. it says "Open with Apth URL". I click that. It gives me the error message.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce the error if I open a script with AptURL. I'm not sure how this happened on your side though. If anything it should open the script in a text editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus), specifically [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/421536/301745). (Nautilus is the codename for the file manager, Files)

Answer (score 8):

It seems like the file needs execution permissions.

This is what worked for me:

- Right click on the file, click on `Properties`.
- On the Permissions tab, make sure you have checked the 'Allow executing file as program'
- Close it and go open the file. It now runs correctly.

[image: screenshot]