# How to make the Tor desktop entry functional

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, tor

I have downloaded [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/11.5.4/tor-browser-linux64-11.5.4_en-US.tar.xz) for Ubuntu `20.04`, but the desktop entry:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ./Browser/execdesktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser is +1 for privacy and −1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
Exec=sh -c '"/home/belal/Desktop/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  ->
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=/home/belal/Desktop/Browser/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

Doesn't work even after [changing execution Permission](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217636), I can run the script from the terminal, but I do like to make it work as a Desktop Entry if possible.

I get the Error:

[image]

Can you please tell me how can I fix that please? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you moved the entire tor-browser_en-US directory to the location where you want to keep it, move into the directory (it contains the `start-tor-browser.desktop` file) and run

```sh
./start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app
```

This will automatically install a `.desktop` launcher in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory, so a working icon will appear in your applications menu.

You can find this information in the `.desktop` file.